# duplicate extension woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

In woocommerce there's some payment gateway extension named bank transfer/check etc. they are like offline payment gateway. How can I Duplicate one of theme and use the same extension in same site. In my country there's a offline payment gateway named [Bkash](http://www.bkash.com/). All i want is to make a offline payment gateway extension of woocommerce like money order/check which will be name as Bkash. The payment instructions will be shown just like as moneyorder/bank transfer. I hope You guys understand my needs.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your code in integrate it with this "base gateway plugin" code then you can install it as a plugin.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-payment-gateway-plugin-base/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible! i already created custom payment gatway for norway country

Woo Commerce Provide [Payment Gatware API](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-api/).

You should have to refer this guide in detail, also take idea of code structure from Default Payment under

> wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/gateways/bacs

Comment: I hope you can write in details. From where I have to start doing . I am new and newbie in coding, specially i don';t know php. I hope you can help me on this issue

Comment: Please check if this codes are ok. though it;s not working http://pastebin.com/WAf547zi

Comment: please reply as soon as possible